# Doing Math with Objective C Double

Tags: objective-c, math, core-graphics, double

I've got this loop in Objective C and need some coaching to get it to work out. I'm trying to calculate the height of four bars based on the numbers stored as strings in array, array. biggestTotal is a string containing the largest of the four objects in array. I previously formatted each of the elements in array as currency.

```
for (int j=0; j<[array count]; j++) {    
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j], [array objectAtIndex:j], biggestTotal);
    double barHeight = (([[array objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue])*400.0/([biggestTotal doubleValue]));
    NSLog(@"%@",barHeight);
    CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake((150.0+(j*125.0)), (425.0-barHeight), 100.0, barHeight); // (x, y, width, height)
    CGContextAddRect(context, currentRect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

With my NSLog statements above, I get Console outputs as follows:

```
0 $106,758.20 $106,758.20
(null)
1 $14,536.69 $106,758.20
(null)
2 $32,111.96 $106,758.20
(null)
3 $100,020.00 $106,758.20
(null)
```

Also, sadly I get no bars. What am I missing here? Why is the barHeight a (null)? Any help would be most appreciated...

Comment: At least for logging the barHeight, use `NSLog(@"%f",barHeight);`.  See [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: (moving from answer to comment) The `(null)` are because you use `%@` to print a `double`. Because of the C calling convention, it prints `(null)`, but this is probably completely coincidental (it could very well be any garbage value, in which case your program would simply crash). You need to use `%f` or `%g` to print doubles.

Comment: A point of programming: don't stored formatted data, only format it when you are displaying it. This helps avoid problems like this, and allows for easier internationalization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`barHeight` is `NULL`* because `@"$106,758.20"` doesn't have a valid `doubleValue`. Get rid of the `$` and the `,`** and it should work.

Also, if you're doing math with currency, [don't use `double`](http://www.lahey.com/float.htm). Use [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI))

---

*Actually `0.0` because it can't be converted, [per the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-doubleValue), but then, as everyone else has pointed out, you're trying to log it with the wrong format specifier: `%@`, which is for objects, not `double`. Since `0x0` is `nil`, and `0x0 == 0.0` :), if you try to `NSLog(@"%@", 0.0);`, you get "(null)" for output. **Also**, if you *do* get a valid return from `doubleValue`, your attempt to use `%@` will very likely result in a crash**, because you'll be trying to touch memory you're not supposed to.

**Credit to [Caleb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827325/doing-math-with-objective-c-double/5827395#5827395) (see comment) for pointing this out.

Comment: I corrected the NSLog formatting and stripped out the , and $. Doing so made the math work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j], [array objectAtIndex:j], biggestTotal);
```

You don't need the `[NSString stringWithFormat...]` bit... NSLog does that for you. Do this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %f", [array objectAtIndex:j], biggestTotal);
```

Also, notice that I used %f instead of %@ as the second format specifier. This is because biggestTotal is a double, not an object pointer. The %@ specifier is for objects only. You'll want to make that same change in your second NSLog() statement.

**Edit:** I see now that you say that biggestTotal is a string, in which case %@ is correct. However, the second NSLog() specifies %@ for barHeight, which *is* a double, so you'll still need to fix that. Your first log statement is printing (null) for biggestTotal, so I suspect you have some problem wherever you create biggestTotal.

Comment: He's trying to convert `@"$106,758.20"`, i.e., string with a dollar sign at the front, using `doubleValue`.

Comment: Right you are... +1 for that. I'm not sure the comma is supported by -doubleValue either. A number formatter is called for here. But if the OP fixes that and gets a non-zero value back for barHeight, it'll crash due to the incorrect format specifier.

Comment: Oh, didn't even think of the comma! Nor of the implications of the format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `%@` is used only for objects, and I have had nothing but problems when I have accidentally used it on primitive datatypes. I just tried it on a double, and it crashed for me. Instead, I use (for doubles):

```
NSLog(@"%lf", barHeight);
```

A comprehensive list can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265